# Update unable to find TableMapping['z'] or DataTable 'z'

Tags: sql, vb.net

```
Private Sub dgviewshow()
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
    da = New SqlDataAdapter("select * from Student", con)
    Dim dset As New DataSet
    da.Fill(dset, "z")
    dgview.DataSource = dset.Tables("z")
    dgview.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill
End Sub 

Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate_1.Click
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
    da = New SqlDataAdapter("select * from Student", con)
    Dim a As New SqlCommandBuilder(da)
    Try
        a.GetUpdateCommand()
        da.Update(dset, "z")
        MsgBox("Successfully updated", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `dgviewshow` method, you populate a `DataTable` in a `DataSet` that is assigned to a local variable `dset`.  In your `Button1_Click_1` method, you are trying to save changes from a `DataSet` assigned to a different `dset` variable.  Presumably it is also a different `DataSet`.  If you want to access the `DataSet` in multiple methods then it must be assigned to a variable that is accessible in multiple methods, i.e. a member variable.  If you're using a member variable, which you must be already or that second method wouldn't compile, then why are you declaring a local variable in the first method at all?

Comment: because if i didnt declared the local variable in the first method, the refreshing of my data grid would have the data values doubled

Comment: Nope. The variable is irrelevant to that. If you `Fill` the same `DataSet` object without clearing it first then of course you'll get double the data. The obvious solution to that is to clear the existing data first though.  Even if you don't do that though, you still don't need a local variable.  You would simply create a new `DataSet` object and assign it to the same member variable as you did in the first place.